# How to add 2 four bit Hexa to make a ASCII char byte

Tags: c++

I have a binary file from a source, from which i have to retrive data so that it is read in human readable form. I have retrived the data and have it in the 4 bit hexa. For eg the file size is 256 byte and i am retrieving it in hexa and getting 512 4 bit hexa values.
Now, to make it human readable ASCII chars, i have to add two 4 bit hexa to make a byte. The way i am retrieving the data in Hex format is

```
byte = read_buffer[i];

// Convert the Most Significant nibble for first byte
write_buffer_hex[(i + 1) * 2 + 0] = hex_chars[(byte >> 4)];

// Convert the Least Significant nibble for the first byte
write_buffer_hex[(i + 1) * 2 + 1] = hex_chars[byte & 0x0f];
```

Now, my question is how should i add these two hex values to have a ASCII value. The way i am doing now is to just add these two, but is it the correct way ??. Thank you

Comment: Isn't `printf` your friend here, or something similar?

Comment: Why are you storing both hexidecimal chars in the same place of an array?  If you put them one after each other, you'd be done.  I'm not sure what you're doing, or what your problem is.

Comment: Whatever you are doing I can assure you that this is not the correct way. It is very hard to follow what you are trying to do. I think you want to just set write_buffer_hex[someindex]=byte and be done with it. Although what exactly is write_buffer_hex defined as?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with John, it may be easier to output it directly in the hexadecimal basis like so:

```
printf("%x", byte);
```

or with C++'s IOstream library:

```
cout << hex << byte;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table:

```
static char const alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

// Loop:

output[cursor++] = alphabet[byte % 16];
output[cursor++] = alphabet[byte / 16];
```

You can index directly into the string, too:

```
output[cursor++] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[byte % 16];
```